# Cannot login via SSH anymore [RHEL7]

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm facing a strange behaviour on SSH login via a simple password.
I have 2 VMs with RHEL 7.4, the second VM works perfect, I can login via SSH using a password. With first VM I got "Permission Denied".
I'm able to login as root (or any other user) via console, so the password is correct (I also reset it). sshd_config is exectly the same between first and second node, so I believe the issue is not in openssh-server.

Here is the complete ssh -vvv log:

> https://pastebin.com/PvAZENSL

It ends with:

```
root@192.21.11.83's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

**EDIT:** I enabled sshd -d as server and I got:
pam password authentication failed for root module is unknown
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4hL7.png
I don't know if this can help to solve the issue!

Could someone point me to a possibile solution?
Thank you very much,
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

**GOT IT!**
Someone have changed some security OS files: /etc/pam.d/sshd and /etc/pam.d/system-auth, in wrong way.
I restored the original file and did:

```
authconfig --updateall
```

Now I'm able again to login via SSH!